# R Store variables from large number of summary tables in columns of new document

Tags: r, csv, summary, r-package

I have a dataframe (X) with 6 columns named: mean.x, s.x, n.x, mean.y, s.y, n.y. They represent means, st dev (s) and sample size (n) from populations x and y. I am running an R package (BSDA) that performs t-test from these statistical parameters. The problem is that for each row I get 1 summary table and I have 640.000 rows.

What I want to do is to create new columns with all the p-values and other parameters from the 640.000 summary tables. Is this possible?

The values for the first 5 rows are the same: mean.x (0.444357), s.x (0.02575427), n.x (633744), mean.y (0.4308), s.y (0.000628747), n.y (390)

This is the script that displays the summary tables:

```
library(BSDA)

tsum.test(mean.x = X$mean.x,
          s.x = X$s.x,
          n.x = X$n.x,
          mean.y = X$mean.y,
          s.y = X$s.y,
          n.y = X$n.y, 
          alternative = "less",
          mu = 0, # null hypothesis that there is no diff between means
          var.equal = FALSE,
          conf.level = 0.95)
```

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible yes. Have a look below. One way would be to use `apply` for this:

Imagine a very simple `data.frame` like this (all rows are the same for this simple example):

```
x  <- c(7.8, 6.6, 6.5, 7.4, 7.3, 7.0, 6.4, 7.1, 6.7, 7.6, 6.8) 
y  <- c(4.5, 5.4, 6.1, 6.1, 5.4, 5.0, 4.1, 5.5) 
X <- data.frame(mean_x = mean(x), s.x = sd(x), n.x = 11, mean_y = mean(y), s.y = sd(y), 
                n.y = 8) 
X <- rbind(X, X, X)

#> X
#    mean_x       s.x n.x mean_y       s.y n.y
#1 7.018182 0.4643666  11 5.2625 0.7069805   8
#2 7.018182 0.4643666  11 5.2625 0.7069805   8
#3 7.018182 0.4643666  11 5.2625 0.7069805   8
```

Then you use an `apply` to run your `tsum.test` on each line and you extract the parameters you need. For the example I extracted `p.values` and the `degrees of freedom`:

```
new_cols <-
apply(X, 1, function(x) {

  #using apply in each iteration, a row will be fed to the tsum.test function
  #so make sure you re using the correct ones
  stats <- 
    #x[1] corresponds to the first column, x[2] to the second and so on
    tsum.test(mean.x = x[1],
          s.x = x[2],
          n.x = x[3],
          mean.y = x[4],
          s.y = x[5],
          n.y = x[6], 
          alternative = "less",
          mu = 0, # null hypothesis that there is no diff between means
          var.equal = FALSE,
          conf.level = 0.95)

  #output p.values and degrees of freedom on this occasion
  c(pvalue = stats$p.value, df = stats$parameters)

})
```

The above outputs the degrees of freedom and the p.values, which in order to bind to your data.frame you can do:

```
   > cbind(X, t(new_cols))
    mean_x       s.x n.x mean_y       s.y n.y pvalue.mean_x    df.df
1 7.018182 0.4643666  11 5.2625 0.7069805   8     0.9999669 11.30292
2 7.018182 0.4643666  11 5.2625 0.7069805   8     0.9999669 11.30292
3 7.018182 0.4643666  11 5.2625 0.7069805   8     0.9999669 11.30292
```

Comment: Thanks so much @LyzandeR !. The only problem is that I don't have the "x"  or "y" values, but only means, st dev and n, so how to deal with "function(x)"?. I am sorry for my ignorance, I am new to R

Comment: You don't need to have x or y variables. I just used those to create the data.frame named `X`. As I understand you do have a data.frame, too. So it is only a matter of selecting the correct columns to go into the `function(x)` in `sapply`. I even made my data.frame as closely related to your example.

Comment: In other words I just used x and y so that i could use the means, sds and the ns. The data.frame X contains exactly those things, so you can just ignore my x and y. Type `X` (capital X)  on your console to have a look at my data.frame.

Comment: Thanks very much @LyzandeR !. It worked great !. 

I knew why you used "x" and "y" values. I was just a bit confused about function(x), cause I did not know what "x" would stand for when using my data :)

Comment: Hi @LizanderR, I am sorry for bothering you again. It seemed yesterday the script worked well but now I am having problems again (I am getting repetitive sets of 5 rows and also 5 p-values per row) and I don't know what happens. I have edited the post with the real values of the first 5 rows. Any suggestion would be welcome. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It worked yesterday which means there is something wrong with how you copied my example. Use a clean session and try again. If it doesnt work please post a new **reproducible** example (i.e. use `dput` to post your data), the code you used and the error you received and someone will help. I am really busy today and I wont be able to spend any time here.